# How to change a text file into a php array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I change a text file with a list of words, each on their own line (**without commas**), into one array, with comma separating?

I guess, what do you use to manipulate PHP arrays and strings to be able to interchange the data?

`explode`?

The file looks like this:

```
This
Is
The
File
I
Want
Changed
```

And I want it it to look like this:

```php
array(
    This,
    Or,
    This,
    Or,
    Even,
    This
);
```

Comment: Are you serious? Do some research. "php file array" Searching those *MAIN* keywords on google, the first thing that pops up is what you need... Don't expect other people to always lead you to the answer, honestly.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it split on each line-break, use

```
$file = file('file.txt');
```

Or, if you have text, not a file, that you want to explode:

```
$file = explode("\n", $text);
```

See [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

---

But next time, *please do your own research*.

Comment: +1 to both of you, But I disagree with your comment: `Next time, please do your own research!`. Indeed until now I did not know how easy is `change a text file into an php array` It is a very good question and answer...

Comment: @NomikOS Did you see Nile's comment on the question? I would say it is fairly easy to do one's own research, but I suppose some people might not think of the right search terms.

Comment: Well, Now because of you I know something new. That's is another good reason to participate in this community! 8)

Comment: most of the time when you search for something like this you get flooded with SO results. most people attempt a few searches but give up quickly and head over here. if you provide a good answer then subsequent searches for "how to change a text file into a php array" will hit this page, theyll get the answer, and wont open a question

Answer (score 2):

Very easy... do this:

```
$arch = file( 'your-file.txt' );
```

Then:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $arch ); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the array, you could use [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function.

```
$array = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Answer (score 1):

text file to change in array:=

```
 $text= 'test.txt';
 $fo= fopen($text,'r');
 $fr = fread($fo,filesize($fo));

 $strarray = explode(' ', $fr);

 print_r($strarray);
```